# What are few good fonts for Flat UI?

Tags: website-design, web-fonts

The next project that we are coding in, we are making the UI flat, can anyone suggest some good fonts that would look good with it and which are freely available.
I like the "`Lato`" font family. Maybe a few more like this?

Comment: I would think most fonts would look fine. The question is, I suppose, what font-families work well together.

Comment: As boblet states, almost anything can work. We'd need a whole lot more context here to make specific suggestions.

Comment: http://www.google.com/fonts; mostly open source fonts, sort by popularity, preview before you download.

Comment: Question is overly broad.

Answer (score 4):

So the Lato font family is what's known as a ['sans-serif'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif) font. If you like it, you should probably look for other sans-serif fonts. The most classic/timeless/respected font would be Helvetica, but its licensing is expensive. A couple free alternatives:

Open Sans: Essentially open-source Helvetica. Always a good choice.

Source Sans Pro: Adobe's take on an open-source modern sans-serif.

Roboto: Google's sans-serif of choice for the Android operating system.

And you can find these and a bunch more free google webfonts [here, on a curated list by SOMA design](http://somadesign.ca/demos/better-google-fonts/). Its a good starting point, if nothing else.

Quick (opinionated) sidenote: A 'flat' design does not inherently have fonts that go well with it or not. Don't limit yourself to whatever FlatUI Pro does - use the toolkit as a starting off point to find your own (or your company/client's own) style. Going a completely different direction with the primary display font can easily achieve that - play around. Typography is a vast world of artistic directions, and there's rarely one correct answer.

Comment: +1 for "A 'flat' design does not inherently have fonts that go well with it".

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the font families that looks good. See if these suits you.

"Roboto","Oswald","Source Sans Pro","Cuprum","Archivo Narrow","Ropa Sans","Gudea"

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

http://font.penshow.cn/199/
 The style of the font, open the download.
The hope can help you。

Comment: Please expand your answer to explain why you think  you have a good solution.

Comment: Web site provides a variety of word, convenient and quick.

Comment: Personal recommend Edwardian Script ITC font